# Call function with argument from dynamically create link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a grid of divs based on JSON that is returned from my server. When I iterate the objects, I create it like this

```
getApps(function(data){
    var displayMode = "<? echo  $_GET['displayMode']; ?>";
    var appsDisplayedCounter = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
        var app = data[i];
        // check if we're interested in this app
        var shouldDisplay = (displayMode == 'hired' && app.hired == 1) || (displayMode == 'self' && app.hired == 0) || !displayMode;

        if (shouldDisplay)
        {
            var innerContent;
            var content = '<div class="AppContainer">';
            if (appsDisplayedCounter % 2 == 0)
            {
                innerContent = '<img class="SquareImage" src="'+app.imagePath+'"/>\
                <div class="AppContainerName AppContainerBottomSegment">'+app.name+'</div>';
            }
            else
            {
                innerContent = '<div class="AppContainerName">'+app.name+'</div>\
                <img class="SquareImage AppContainerBottomSegment" src="'+app.imagePath+'"/>';
            }

            content = content + innerContent + '</div>';
            // nest the content in a link
            content = '<a href="javascript:showDetailView('+app+')" id="'+app.name+'">' + content + '</a>';
            $(".MainContentContainer").append(content);

            // link handler
            //$('#'+app.name).click(function(){showDetailView(app.name); return false});

            // increment counter
            appsDisplayedCounter++;
        }
    }
});

function showDetailView(app)
{
    alert(app);
}

function getApps(completion)
{
    $.ajax({
    url:    '/Apps.php',
    success: function(data)
        {
            var appsJson = data['apps'];
            completion(appsJson);
        },
    async:   false
    });

}
```

My issue is passing the `app` object into my function. Clicking the div does nothing.

-- EDIT --

When I inspect the tag after it was created, it looks like this

```
<a id="AppName" href="javascript:showDetailView([object Object])">
```

I set a breakpoint in `showDetailView(app)` which is never called when I click this link.

Comment: What error are you getting? Where is the exact line of code that you think is causing problems? What exactly is going on? I don't really want to figure out your entire function to help you, this question is just a code dump and you saying "this is broke".

Comment: JavaScript Objects don't become a parsable String, by default. What you're seeing in the tag [is the standard](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.4.2). You'll have to specify how to format each `app` so they can be understood within an `href`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting `[object Object]` because you are referencing it as a string, but it's not a string.

If you are trying to pass the entire object into the function, then you should use `JSON.Stringify()`

```
content = '<a href="javascript:showDetailView('+ JSON.stringify(app) +')"
                     id="'+app.name+'">' + content + '</a>';
```

Then in your showDetailView function:

```
function showDetailView(app) {
    var appJSON = JSON.parse(app);
    alert(aJSON.name);
}
```

---

### References

- [JSON Object Overview](http://www.json.org/js.html)
- [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)
- [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)